# Can't access BIOS settings through F2

Tags: bios

I have a DELL Optiplex GX260 Series, and umm I can't access my bios settings, F2 gives me the setup and F12 the Boot Menu. There are no advanced settings in my setup as well. I have searched everywhere and I can't seem to rectify this problem. Please HELP!!

I need to install Windows XP on my desktop, my CD-ROM does not work so I am using a USB drive for installation and I need to change my Bios Boot settings. So I really need the BIOS settings, any ideas? And oh I tried Pressing DELETE as well, didn't work.

Comment: You should turn `legacy usb` support on. Use one of the front usb ports and F12 should be sufficient to select your USB drive.

Comment: Legacy usb support? Whats that? By the way I am using the front port, I have my USB inserted there!

Comment: The title states you can't access the BIOS, but you also say "F2 gives me the setup". Can you enter the BIOS or not?

Comment: I enter the system setup, and I cant seem to find any option to enter into the BIOS settings.

Comment: Also, have you updated your BIOS? If not I would try that as per: http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/desktop/f/3514/p/18057847/18181389.aspx

Comment: `Integrated devices (Legacy select options)`, `USB emulation ON` is needed for USB boot.

Comment: @Vmai can you be a little more clear please?

Answer (score 0):

At http://www.mss.net/Links/DellDocs/OptiGX260/UserGuide/advfeat.htm#1101572 there's a section that says:

> HDD Priority
>
> ```
> HDD (default)
> USB Device
> ```
>
> NOTE: To boot from a USB memory device, select the USB device and move
>   it to make it the first device.

I think that might be what you need to find and do.

Comment: @brack I tried your suggestion and updated my BIOS and as chuck suggested, yep I got the USB Device option in my BOOT MENU but when i tried to boot from it i got this error saying that NTLDR is missing so I am trying to figure out another issue here. It never stops.

Comment: I did everything you guys suggested but I still get this error NTLDR misiing when i try to boot through my USB. Any ideas or help?

Comment: Your USB is probably not bootable... what did you use to make it?